# NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException On iOS 9.3 With SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

So I'm making some small projects for a major game that I've been developing, but without knowing why, everytime I try to run my Game a SIGABRT error prompts with the following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (GameScene) for key (root); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'

I've added the following extension to SKNode

```
    extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(_ file: NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = Bundle.main().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
            do {
                let sceneData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSData.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: sceneData)
                archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
                let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
                archiver.finishDecoding()
                return scene
            } catch {
                print("ERROR1002")
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            print("ERROR001 - pathForResource not found")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I've used this extension in other projects and everything ran like a charm, but now on this one.

When my game lanches, my GameViewController.swift File is called and on my **viewDidLoad** method I do the following:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit




class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile(currentSKSFile) as? GameScene {

            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .landscape
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        print("didReceiveMemoryWarning ERRO - GameViewController.swift")
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

I've debugged the code and it crashes on the following line in the extension class I've added:

> let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene

And it prompts the error described above.

I'm running Xcode 8 Beta + iOS 10, and no, it's not because of this, because I can run the exact same extension used in other projects on this kind of devices with Beta versions without any error.

Any hint on what might be causing this?

Regards - Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow cleaning my project solved my issues!

I have tried different stuff and the errors were there, so I've cleaned it and the error wasn't there anymore.

I don't know why that happened , but it's solved.

Thanks anyway :)